Generating MySQL Dump via Instance started from AMI
I have a live ec2 server instance running with MySQL installed locally (not using RDS), and another backup server that runs MySQL replication as a slave to the live server.
I am now trying to generate daily automated SQL dumps, and so far I've been researching on AWS CLI to automate the whole process by

start an instance with AMI snapshot of live server (backup done daily)
run the mysql dump command
terminate the instance and delete the volume.

I got it working fully (the commands and so on), but I noticed an issue is that, the MySQL in the instance started via AMI is very slow, it takes 2-3x longer duration to generate a full backup (compared to doing it in live server).
I tried to not do it in the backup/slave server as we want the backup server's data to always be ready, but generating a mysqldump will temporarily require pausing of slave and resuming it later (meaning to say, there will be a lag for xx period of time, whereby xx is the time taken for mysql dump to be generated).
Is there any better solutions to this? We're not using RDS mainly due to the cost, hence we're doing it all manually.
My goal is to create multiple sql backup files, by table, in a sense, 1 file for 1 table, but each of the files must have the same cut-off dates in terms of data.

How exactly are you generating the AMI snapshots? Do you shut down the MySQL server when doing that, or do you perform the snapshot on a running server?

@kovshenin its automated by AWS (Lifecycle Manager) that generates a snapshot without restarting the server (so no shut downs at all)

It's hard to tell why exactly performing the backup on new instance takes 2-3x longer, but here are some things to check/consider:

Is the instance class the same as the production instance? Less CPU/memory on the backup instance can certainly contribute to the time it takes to perform a full backup.
If it's an EBS-backed instance, is the attached volume the same storage class and size as the production instance, i.e. provisioned IOPS number?
If the AMI snapshot is taken during a running instance while MySQL is running, some data might not be flushed to disk and some MySQL files might remain in a dirty state. When booting the new instance, it may take extra time to run some recovery checks and procedures to get the server in a clean state.


Is there any better solutions to this? We're not using RDS mainly due to the cost, hence we're doing it all manually.
but generating a mysqldump will temporarily require pausing of slave and resuming it later

You can create a database dump from the replica (or the primary) without locking the tables or pausing it in any way. Look at --single-transaction if you're using InnoDB, some explanation about that here.
Update: If you're looking to create separate files for separate tables in a single transaction, without having to lock the individual tables, there's a --tab argument you can use with mysqldump: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html

i need to pause the slave cause i don't want to create a full backup on the whole database, but instead, i want 1 file/table. creating a full backup on the whole database is not efficient when we only need the data from 1 (or few) table and fast.

Assuming you use InnoDB tables, you can tell mysqldump which specific tables you would like, and still generate the export in a single transaction, without having to pause anything, which would be pretty fast and efficient: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax

sorry if my statement was confusing. I want 1 file per table. I have 400 tables, so i want 400 .sql.gz files as my output, and all of them must have the same data (eg, all data is up to 10:00:00am)

Ah. Did you try using --tab for separate files? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html

Thanks! Just found out about this feature. Seems to kind of fulfill what I want, which means I can run this on the slave server as well. Will give it a try soon, roughly tested, the data is in text file format and tab delimited. Might need to further research on how to zip it and if it's straight away usable (never mingled with tab delimited sql files thus far).

ok. this (using --tab) actually works, with some caveats. Can you edit your answer to include that, and I will accept it as answered.

Edited, thank you!

Its very easy to tell why the backup is taking much longer.
Although the snapshot exists as soon as AWS tells you it exists, at this point it is just a set of pointers to the original data. In the background, AWS is running a copy job to populate the data. If you attempt to read something from the snapshot which is not yet populated, your read call blocks, AWS puts the request at the top of the replication list and you need to wait until that data has been populated. This data population is called "hydration".
The only way to get around this is to have another replica running all the time.

start an instance with AMI snapshot of live server

So unless you are stopping the live server to create the snapshot, that also means there's a long pause on starting up the new instance for MySQL to run through crash recovery. You might consider using a snapshot of the temporarily stopped replica you already have to avoid this.
Once you have a replica with fully populated data, it is only being used for  running mysqlbackup (I.e. VERY low concurrency) then you can make the backup go faster by increasing the readahead (up to 8x the default).
Alternatively (or subject to testing, in combination) you might consider using Percona Xtrabackup - this will backup using multiple threads.
i.e. the reasons its slow (in estimated order of impact) are:
  1=) snapshot hydration
  1=) Crash recovery
  3) IO latency
  4) CPU

An alternative approach would be to create a filesystem snapshot on the host rather than a block device AWS snapshot (no copy required). Then you can mount that on the host and use the raw data files for the backup, or, spin up a second instance of mysql on the same host to access the snapshot and run mysqlbackup.
Or just treat the AWS snapshot AS the backup.
